# Laravel validator, add parameter on validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have begun tinkering with validators in Laravel and seem to have programmed myself into a corner.

**Background**

I have a method which I use to check if an address exists through Google Maps. Since I started having just one file and validation in that file I just let it return an object containing if longitude and latitude matched and the formated address.

```
return (object) ['result' => (bool) $match, 'formatedAddress' => (string) $googleMaps->formatted_address];
```

(Typecast for clarity, no actual typecast in code at this point.)

This worked well in the controller since I could reuse the variables within the method, but not so well after moving it to `AppServiceProvider`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make `Validator::extend()` set a public parameter upon validation so I can reach the formatted address? Or do I have to go about doing this in another way?

Using PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer while tinkering a bit more. I made an error in my conditions so it did not even reach the point where I set the variable.
Basically, this is the solution:

```
Validator::extend('location', function (
    $attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator
) {
    $validator->location = true;
}
```

Hope my slight error and oversight can help someone else to not get stuck in the same way.